# Jquery: remove/reset onerror event of img tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

in my code, there are some img tags that has onerror event on it.
example:
`<img onerror=alert(11) src=a>`

is there a way in jquery to remove all ierror events on image tags? or maybe reset the onerror so the alert will not trigger? like this:

```
<img onerror="" src=a>
```

or

```
<img src=a>
```

thanks in advance!

PS: i tried using these codes:

```
$('img').each(function(){
this.onerror = "";
});
```

then this one:

```
$('*').each(function(){      
        if ($(this).is('img')) {
            $(this).unbind('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: _in my code, there are some img tags that has onerror event on it_ why don't delete it in the code instead of create a function for block that?

Comment: It's unlikely to work, as by the time the DOM is ready and the jQuery/JS runs to remove the `onerror` function call, the image has already been loaded (or the attempt to load it has started) and the function will fire regardless. To fix this you need to improve your HTML by removing the inline event attributes entirely.

Comment: Or fix it so they don't error...

Comment: this has to work `this.onerror = "";` but you script must be after all img tags

Comment: You could *possibly* do *something* like `$("img").each(function(i,e) { this.outerHTML = this.outerHTML.replace(/onerror=[^\>\s]/g, "") });` - or *something like that*...

Comment: the image tags were created dynamically, so the onerror events cannot be removed manually. i tried using the codes on console, but the onerrors are still there.

Comment: and by the way, this is a continued project, if i remove the script that generates alert onerror, it will affect the whole website so im trying to create a script for the specific page.